# VSCode: Set C/C++ preprocessor macro for static analysis

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, visual-studio-code, preprocessor-directive

I am developing a library which lets user set a crucial type alias, or do it through preprocessor directives.
This type alias (or the directive) is undeclared in the library, by design. Thus, when developing my code I get annoying error messages and squiggles for this undeclared type. This could be avoided if I declare a temporary type for it somewhere. However, I do not like the idea of declaring it when I work with the code and then remove it when I publish it. It is also bug prone, since I could easily forget to remove it.

**My question is:** *Can I define preprocessor directives for VS Code's static analysis (IntelliSense? C/C++ Extension)?*

That would let me consider the analysis like what a well defined type alias would produce. And avoid annoying error messages/squiggles.

---

**Minimal reproducable example:**

[Online compiler example](https://www.online-cpp.com/NrEVMj316l)

*tCore.hpp*

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

// User is responsible of declaring the tCore type

// tCore interface methods 
template<typename TCore>
std::string printImpl();
```

*tPrint.hpp*

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class tPrint {
  public:
    tPrint() = default;
      
    void print() const {
        std::cout << printImpl<tCore>() << std::endl; // <-- Static analysis error here!
    }
};
```

*tFoo.hpp - tCore candidate*

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "tCore.hpp"

struct tFoo {};

template<>
std::string printImpl<tFoo>() {
    return "tFoo";
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <tFoo.hpp>

using tCore = tFoo;

int main() {
    tPrint p{};
    p.print();  // -> "tFoo"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is this a typo? `tMicrocontroller` vs  `tMicroprocessor` ?

Comment: I dont understand the question. One the one hand you say the type has to be supplied by the user on the other hand you want to provide specialisations for a limited set of types (like eg for `tATtiny85`)

Comment: can you try to make the [mcve] more minimal?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 yes. I messed up bad with a LOT of misplacing these. It is edited now though. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I guess I can make it more simple. Will do.

Comment: looks better but still typos. I suppose  `std::cout << print<tCore>() << std::endl;` should be `std::cout << printImpl<tCore>() << std::endl;`, no? But anyhow, why is `tPrint` not a template?

Comment: Readability and convinience. I do not want the user to have to clutter his/her code with templates. Especially since almost every class (template) in the library would have to be implemented for every construction. The user would have to mess around with their own preprocessor directives to deploy code continuosly to instances using different `tPrint<T>` etc. By abstracting away this with the `tCore` type, the user would only have to set a control directive according to documentation and not have to understand all the details. `tCore` is in reality a type representing different hardware.

Comment: I just realized my new minimal example really does not show any of the preprocessor directives I am talking about. I am sorry about that.

I will just create an answer with my solution and leave this post. Sorry for being a bit unclear, @largest_prime_is_463035818.

Answer (score 7):

I found out it was *IntelliSense* causing the error through the *C/C++ Extension*.

I also found an option of adding compiler arguments to *IntelliSense*, which is exactly what I was looking for.

#### Either through the UI:

Press
F1 -> `> C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)` ->  Scroll down to `Defines`

#### Or via the JSON :

`c_cpp_properties.json` configurations has a field `defines` which holds any compiler arguments.